# VHDL: why the time difference between input, output is 1.5 clock cycle rather than 1?

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity buffer_d_e is
  port(
    clk:in std_logic;
    clr:in std_logic;

    in_RegDst:in std_logic;
    out_RegDst:out std_logic;

    in_MemRead:in std_logic;
    out_MemRead:out std_logic;

    in_MemtoReg:in std_logic;
    out_MemtoReg:out std_logic;

    in_MemWrite:in std_logic;
    out_MemWrite:out std_logic;

    in_ALUop:in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    out_ALUop:out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

    in_ALUsrc:in std_logic;
    out_ALUsrc:out std_logic;

    in_RegWrite:in std_logic;
    out_RegWrite:out std_logic;

    in_read_data_1:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    out_read_data_1:out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

    in_read_data_2:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    out_read_data_2:out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

    in_sign_ext:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    out_sign_ext:out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

    in_func:in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    out_func:out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

    in_instr_20_16:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    out_instr_20_16:out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

    in_instr_15_11:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    out_instr_15_11:out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

    in_instr_25_21:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    out_instr_25_21:out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)
  );
end buffer_d_e;

architecture behavioral of  buffer_d_e is
  signal s_RegDst,s_MemRead,s_MemtoReg,s_MemWrite,s_ALUsrc,s_RegWrite:std_logic;
  signal s_ALUop:std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  signal s_instr_20_16,s_instr_15_11,s_instr_25_21:std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  signal s_func:std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
  signal s_read_data_1,s_read_data_2,s_sign_ext:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

  begin
  process(clk,clr)
    begin
    if clr='1'
      then 
      s_RegDst<='X';
      s_MemRead<='X';
      s_MemtoReg<='X';
      s_MemWrite<='X';
      s_ALUop<="XX";
      s_ALUsrc<='X';
      s_RegWrite<='X';
      s_read_data_1<="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
      s_read_data_2<="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
      s_sign_ext<="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
      s_func<="XXXXXX";
      s_instr_20_16<="XXXXX";
      s_instr_15_11<="XXXXX";
      s_instr_25_21<="XXXXX";
    elsif clk'event  AND clk='1'
      THEN 
      s_RegDst<=in_RegDst; 
      s_MemRead<=in_MemRead;
      s_MemtoReg<=in_MemtoReg;
      s_MemWrite<=in_MemWrite;
      s_ALUop<=in_ALUop;
      s_ALUsrc<=in_ALUsrc;
      s_RegWrite<=in_RegWrite;
      s_read_data_1<=in_read_data_1;
      s_read_data_2<=in_read_data_2;
      s_sign_ext<=in_sign_ext;
      s_func<=in_func;
      s_instr_20_16<=in_instr_20_16;
      s_instr_15_11<=in_instr_15_11;
      s_instr_25_21<=in_instr_25_21;
    end if;
      out_RegDst<=s_RegDst; 
      out_MemRead<=s_MemRead;
      out_MemtoReg<=s_MemtoReg;
      out_MemWrite<=s_MemWrite;
      out_ALUop<=s_ALUop;
      out_ALUsrc<=s_ALUsrc;
      out_RegWrite<=s_RegWrite;
      out_read_data_1<=s_read_data_1;
      out_read_data_2<=s_read_data_2;
      out_sign_ext<=s_sign_ext;
      out_func<=s_func;
      out_instr_20_16<=s_instr_20_16;
      out_instr_15_11<=s_instr_15_11;
      out_instr_25_21<=s_instr_25_21;
  end process;
end behavioral;
```

Code above is a simple code for buffer. 'clr' is a clear signal, 'clk'is a clock. My confusion is that the [simulation result of this buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4S7O.png) shows the input and output time interval is 1.5 clock cycle rather than 1 clock cycle.(s_addr1_same and s_rse are input and output of buffer respectively) But why it happens and how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've included output assignments in the same process as your registers. Unfortunately those signals representing registers are not in the sensitivity list for the process.  No signal assignment takes effect while any process is active. The extra half clock delay comes from clk being in the sensitivity edge where the falling edge assigns the value of your outputs.  You could move the output assignments to a separate process or make them concurrent signal assignments (outside a process).

Comment: @user1155120  I followed your way put signal assignments out of process and succeed. Thank you so much. And could you explain the difference between them?

Comment: A concurrent signal assignment is elaborated as an equivalent process statement which will have any signal found in an expression in a waveform element in it's implicit wait statement (sensitivity list). So using concurrent statements you assign the outputs as soon as there's an event on it's signal source, while in the process without the signal sources in the sensitivity list you wait until the next event (which happens to be the falling edge of the clock).